# Wortstellung bei "was ich Neues..."

Tags: word-order, nominalization

Beim Satz

> Ich freue mich darauf, was ich Neues erfahren werde.

wieso sind "was" und "Neues" durchs Subjekt getrennt? Was ist der Unterschied zwischen dieser Konstruktion und "etwas Neues", welches immer zusammen geschrieben zu finden ist?

Comment: Wie kommst du darauf, dass "etwas Neues" immer zusammen steht?."Etwas für mich Neues", "etwas vollkommen Neues",....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*was* kann ein Fragewort oder ein Pronomen sein. Nur das Pronomen kann auch die erweiterte Form *etwas* haben.

> Ich habe (et)was gelernt.
>   Was hast du gelernt?
>   *Etwas hast du gelernt?

Genau parallel ist es übrigens mit *wer*.

> Ich habe {wen, jemand} kennengelernt.
>   Wen hast du kennengelernt?
>   *Jemand hast du kennengelernt?

Eine Apposition kann nur zum Pronomen, aber nicht zum Fragewort hinzutreten.

> Ich habe {wen, jemand} Interessanten kennengelernt.
>   Ich habe (et)was Neues gelernt.
>   *Wen Interessanten hast du kennengelernt?
>   *Was Neues hast du gelernt?

Fragewörter lassen sich durchaus auch erweitern, wenn auch nicht durch Nomen.

> Wo in Dortmund ist das genau?
>   Wann am Montag wird gestreikt?
>   Wer von deinen Freunden macht das?
>   Was an Neuem haben Sie bei Newtopia gesehen?

In allen obigen Fällen ist auch Distanzstellung möglich, also zum Beispiel:

> Was haben Sie bei Newtopia an Neuem gesehen?

In dieser Stellung kann nun *an Neuem* durch *Neues* ersetzt werden.

> Was haben Sie bei Newtopia Neues gesehen?